# Translate Woocommerce Add to cart button & Cart widget

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, translation, polylang

I have a problem with translating the Add to cart button on woocommerce.

My website is: http://test.mk/OPA
The website is in albanian and english. First language is English.

I have installed Polylang Pro plugin and also tried with Loco translate.

I have changed the "name" of the Add to cart button with this code in functions.php:

```
 //To change add to cart text on single product page
     add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woocommerce_custom_single_add_to_cart_text' ); 
function woocommerce_custom_single_add_to_cart_text() {
return __( 'Order Now', 'woocommerce' ); 
}

// To change add to cart text on product archives(Collection) page
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woocommerce_custom_product_add_to_cart_text' );  
function woocommerce_custom_product_add_to_cart_text() {
    return __( 'Order Now', 'woocommerce' );
}
```

So, what I really need to translate is Order Now.

I added the string using this code:

```
add_action('init', function() {
  pll_register_string('woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'Order Now', 'WooCommerce');
});
```

It is in strings in the polylang plugin, but it is not translating.

Does someone know how to help me to translate the button & the Cart wiget that is also in the website?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Go see ths post: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40456/how-to-override-existing-plugin-action-with-new-action You should fist remove `init` action and then add your action

Comment: What is my action?

Comment: On the site you indicated I correctly display ***Order Now*** as the text of the add to cart button, shouldn't that be so?

Comment: I am trying to translate that 'Order Now' to albanian "Porosit tani' in the Albanian version of the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this function:

```
// change the text of the add to cart button according to the language
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woocommerce_custom_single_add_to_cart_text', 99, 1 ); 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woocommerce_custom_single_add_to_cart_text', 99, 1 );
function woocommerce_custom_single_add_to_cart_text( $text ) {

    // returns the current language "Polylang"
    switch ( pll_current_language() ) {
        case 'en':
            return __( 'Order Now', 'woocommerce' );
        case 'sq':
            return __( 'Porosit tani', 'woocommerce' );
    }

    return $text;
}
```

Change the text of the "Add to cart" button **according to the current language of the site**.

This function should work but I believe you should search the Polylang plugin documentation to correctly translate the string.

*The code must be inserted in the functions.php file of the active theme.*

Comment: This code works, yes. What I am trying to do is to translate the ' Order Now ' button on the albanian version of the website. I am using polylang.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Let me know if it works.

Comment: It does work, you are great!! I have to  save this. Thank you a million!